# How many Stack Exchange sites are there really?

Tags: bug, tour

How many Stack Exchange sites are there? Obviously 114, from the Topbar:

[image: From the Topbar]

Or 112, from Stack Overflow, Help, Tour, scroll to near the bottom.

[image: Help, Tour, scroll to the bottom]

The difference is Area 51 from the link on the Tour page is not listed as a site (which it is from the Topbar), but it has its own link.

And Stack Overflow em Português is missing from the list which shows 112.

Duplicate? Well, OK. I was under the impression that the Topbar was a recent thing, Status Completed and the counts are the other way around on the dupe, but...

Comment: They multiply so fast that it's always... caching... :P

Comment: Nope, I have screenshots from before 25 December, 110 shown on em Portugues, 112 from SO itself, 114 from the Topbar. Too long for caching... Then em Portuguese caught up to 112.

Comment: It's 112 according to SE.com as well. Not that I can be bothered to count...

Comment: Private beta. It's always private beta.

Comment: @PompousQWoodger It was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Mysticial Ah. I have my own caching. Sometimes such things take time to sink in. Sorry.

Comment: @Yannis I don't think so, I checked on that one. Figures the other way around, Status Completed.

Comment: This question would receive different answers in time and so will elicit a forum discussion. 113 now .. 115 tommorrow and so forth... My comment is: it's more of a feature request. And my critics is: you have no idea and haven't worked on your solution. It's indeed only different data.

Comment: @Xsi ? In one place two sites are regarded as Stack Exchange sites, and in another they are not treated in the same way (both treated differently). What Feature would you like this to be? Surely it just needs to be rationalised, by SE, in whatever is the best way to do it, bearing in mind all the stuff that they know about it.

Comment: Ok lets compare. It's interesting. <a href="//stackexchange.com" class="topbar-icon icon-site-switcher js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.show" title="A list of all 114 Stack Exchange sites"> 

###>MAIN<### : <ul class="stats">
                <li>112 <a href="/sites" class="lighter-link">Q&amp;A sites</a></li>

Comment: class="topbar-icon icon-site-switcher js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track" ###>MAIN<### : class="lighter-link" ###>NOTICE: 4 classes are much more comparing to #MAIN-page (mb it's underdone.. underupdated.. unsyncronized..).